# insert to MongoDB array with axios, restAPI and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, axios

I am trying to add an item to a MongoDB array with RESTAPI through Axios. I thought it would look similar to the push method but I have no idea how to do that.

my Model is of a person:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    friends: [],
    missions: []
})

const personModel = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

I want to add a mission to the *mission* array of a person.

and for example, in order to add a new Person, I use NodeJS and API:
(api.js)

```
router.post('/api/people', (req, res) => {
    const personToAdd = req.body;
    const newPersonPost = new personModel(personToAdd);
    newPersonPost.save((e) => {
        if (e) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
    res.json({
        msg: 'Received'
    })
});
```

and in the client side I use Axios:

```
axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/people',
                method: 'POST',
                data: dataToUpdate
            })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('axios sent info to server');
                }).catch((e) => {
                    console.log('error' + e);
                })
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**express**

```
router.post('updating mission endpoint url', async (req, res) =>
try {
const query = { /* content */}; /* write a query to retrieve the concerned user by using a unique identifier */
let person = await personModel.findOne(query); 
person.missions.push(req.body.mission); 

personModel.save(); 
} catch (err) { 
console.log(err); 
} 
});
```

**client**

In the client side you just have to put the mission you want to add in data like you did above with the right endpoint url and you should add a unique identifier for the user you want to add mission to.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` will not assign array type to your variable.

Change your schema file with the following:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    friends: { type: Array },
    missions: { type: Array }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the db model entity file with following

First method:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    friends: {type : Array},
    missions: {type : Array}
})

const personModel = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

Second Method :

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
        const PersonSchema = new Schema({
            name: String,
            password: String,
            friends: [{ type: String }],
            missions: [{ type: String }]
        })
        
        const personModel = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

You can update the array object as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to be using the [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update operator, very simple, like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{
  _id: user._id
},
{
  "$push": {
    "missions": {
      mission: newMission
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ktp5sJ6pvSt)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. can you please elaborate a little? where should I write this code? on the client side? and how do I connect to the DB without API?

Comment: No no, on the server side. you can't connect to the DB without an API, Atlas is offering a serverless offering which is the only service I know which exposes such API's with no server.